# Python CSV matching and combining data from two files (matching people to addresses using postcode)

Tags: python, sorting, csv, merge

I have a csv file that contains lots of postcodes [postcode, street, town, city] and a second csv file that contains friends but only [name, housenumber, postcode]

How could I create a new file that will iterate through the friends, looking in the postcode file for the corresponding address and then combining the relevant rows to make something like [name, housenumber, street, town, city, postcode].

Thanks

Andy

Answer (score 0):

If the files are not very large (I am assuming that there are not millions of friends) you could import both csv's into memory as dictionaries and then do a lookup based on postcode from once and then do a dictionary `update` with the value of the other.

```
for friend in friends:
   friend.update(postcodes[friend.postcode])
```

this is assuming that you will have an array of friends such as:

```
friends = [
    {'name': 'john smith', 'postcode': '123abc', 'housenumber': 12},
    ...
]
```

and a postcode dictionary such as:

```
postcodes = {
    '123abc': {'postcode': '123abc', 'street': 'some street name', 'town': 'a town', 'city': 'a city'},
    ...
}
```

Hope this helps